# Interpreting functions of graphs

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

[image]
The question asked which of the following is false. I narrowed it down to two, and the correct answer is E with it doesn't cross the x-axis at all.
D. f(x) * g(x) intersect the x-axis three times
E. ${\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$ intersects the x-ais more than once

I'm really baffled on how to choose between the two. I thought if I chose a part where f(x) is positive and g(x) is negative then the quotient would be negative, so it'll cross the x-axis.

Comment: In order for $f(x)g(x)$ to be $0$ either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ must be $0$.  In order for $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ to be zero then $f(x)$ must be zero.

Comment: @Nate, you should write your comment as an answer so that this question will not remain unanswered.